# Having a problem with tensorflow module after installing it

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried to run tensorflow from vs code but every time it shows this error that I don't know how to solve. Thank you!

```
2023-06-29 17:46:02.591451: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-06-29 17:46:02.822224: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-06-29 17:46:02.822996: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dahe/Nuclear Launch Codes/PYTHON/lol.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_lib.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column import *
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 143, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.layers import base
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers import base
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/activations.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import advanced_activations
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer_utils
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute.coordinator import cluster_coordinator as coordinator_lib
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/coordinator/cluster_coordinator.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import parameter_server_strategy_v2
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/parameter_server_strategy_v2.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import cross_device_ops as cross_device_ops_lib
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_ops.py", line 19, in <module>
    import multiprocessing.dummy
  File "/home/dahe/Nuclear Launch Codes/PYTHON/multiprocessing.py", line 9, in <module>
    from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
ImportError: cannot import name 'Process' from partially initialized module 'multiprocessing' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/dahe/Nuclear Launch Codes/PYTHON/multiprocessing.py)
```

Comment: Do not name one of your scripts the same as a built-in python module (multiprocessing in this case).

Comment: if you exposed a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) i expect that @Dr.Snoopy would be correct and users could correct the exact error.

Comment: @D.L We can see all of this already in the traceback, no need for a reproducible example.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy.  you read the tracebacks better than i do in that respect.  I would usually validate by cross-referencing the error message with the specific code line.